# Using credentials in Jenkins Promoted Builds

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Outside of chaining separate Jenkins builds together, is there a way within a single build to get credentials (via binding or otherwise) or Injected Passwords available for use within the Promoted Builds plugin?

I'm using other environment variables that I wrote to a file in my build step and then read in using the `Inject environment variables`, but I was not looking to repeat that for a secret used at deploy/promotion time.

Note: I am using Jenkins 2.45

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to use the credentials for the runtime of my application in the promoted environment (i.e. something like setting environment variables for the application once promoted). Used in a similar vein to Vault, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this doesn't look possible, it is marked as a bug in the Jenkins tracker:

[JENKINS-14169 Injected env variables not available for use in processing promotion.](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14169)